# columndefinition using spring roo

Tags: spring-roo

I am using spring roo for generating the pojo classes and the database structures.

While using spring roo specific database DDL generation's cannot be achieved. Like setting the length for the integer variable, setting date fields etc.

In hibernate using the columnDefinition specific operations can be done. But I cant see any command/options for adding this from spring roo.

Is there a way to add columnDefinition to the column annotation using any spring roo command or the option is to create spring roo addon

Answer (score 0):

When adding a `String` to your entity use e.g., the `--sizeMin` property in the console

```
field string --fieldName name --notNull --sizeMin 2 --sizeMax 100
```

When using `Number` try `e.g., --decimal Max`

```
field number --fieldName number --type float --notNull --decimalMax 100 --decimalMin
```

There are many properties which can be set just explore them by entering `--` and pressing ctrl + space.

**Update from comments:**

When adding a date try these:

```
field date --fieldName myDate --type java.util.Date --notNull --persistenceType JPA_DATE 
field date --fieldName myYear --type java.util.Date --notNull --dateTimeFormatPattern yyyy --permitReservedWords
```

Check out the Roo reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-persistence.html

Comment: I cant see an attribute for adding a columnDefinition in spring Roo.

Comment: What is missing? You can define `--notNull`, `--sizeMax` and so on. Normally you should be able to replace your `columnDefinition` by a set of other JPA attributes

Comment: For an example, if i want to use a Date field which holds date and time in the database, i will specify the @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) in the entity class. But while creating the db structure using the Hibernate hbm2ddl tool this will create a db field with TimeStamp type, which can hold only time part. So I have to specify the @ColumnDefinition as Date, which will create the db field as Date type.

Comment: Likewise for a integer if i have to set the size of the integer to 2, there is no options. The attributes like 'decimalMax,max, digitsInteger' etc will set the maximum value only not the size of the field. This is the reason am going for columnDefinition.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo command just help you to create an entity and its properties. For fine-grain column definition you must add/modify the [@Column annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html):

```
 @Column(name="ORDER_COST", updatable=false, precision=12, scale=2)
 private BigDecimal cost;
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking whether there is any options in Roo to add columnDefinition. If its not available then I will create an addon for this.

Comment: Papps, another way is to improve the current Roo add-on. Feel free to contribute to Roo https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo